# Physical/virtual network setup

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, kvm, virt-manager, pfsense

I am setting up a server and am struggling with network setup.

This is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

The problems I have:

1) How to assign "Ethernet" to "Pfsense" so that "Host" has no access to "Ethernet"?"

2) How to make sure that "Host", "VM1" and "WiFi" are on the same network?

3) What's the best approach of creating a WiFi hotspot in the same virtual network, using "WiFi" interface?

- Main part of this is learning, so for simplicity, let's say configuration is done through `virt-manager`.
- I mentioned "PFsense" only in case it puts any restrictions on the network configuration. If it doesn't, it can be anything else.

Comment: i can't really see the point of running your firewall on the VM rather than on the host (the host will be connected to the wifi and should have firewall rules protecting it from that anyway), but see http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#PCI_Passthrough_of_host_network_devices for "Ethernet".  Also, the pfsense vm needs a tap or bridge interface to the "WiFi" network.  Use `hostapd` (and a dhcp server) to create a wifi hotspot.

Comment: Thanks! I will need this physical server for other uses, which I won't be able to achieve under pfsense/freebsd (or won't know how to). Unless pfsense can run a VM server, but quick googling did not yield much and it seems too "dirty". My system does not support iommu; I tried passing through a usb ethernet adapter, but the guest did not recognise it. I understand `hostapd` and dhcp server should  run on the host, not or on the pfsense VM, right?